# Intellij 2017.2.1 issue with generated code JPA

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I recently upgraded to intellij idea version 2017.2.1, I am working on Spring JPA project where we use the generated code for JPA entities. When i try to a module in intellij it keeps throwing error can not find the generated code. I followed all the solutions i found on stack overflow but nothing seems to work, Does anyone else also had similar issue with iintellij latest version upgrade.  Also once i reverted back to the version 2017.1.5 it works fine with generated code. Seems to be a bug in intellij latest release. If anyone else has seen or fixed this issue please let me know.

Comment: DO you mean "Generate persistence mapping" action? Can you add a screenshot, showing the actions you take and the error you are getting?

Comment: If it seems like a bug, report it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Yes its happening for generated persistence mapping I already downgraded to the previous version of IntelliJ and issue disappeared, so i can't really attach the screenshot.